# How to Import contacts from different social apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, contacts, import-contacts

I am developing a social application using ASP.net and C# under .Net Framework 4.0.

I need to provide a facility to import/export contacts from the following:

- Gmail
- AOL
- Yahoo
- Hotamil
- Microsoft Outlook Express

Until now, I only find the way for importing/exporting contacts at gmail using [Google Contact Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/). Does anyone know how to deal with rest of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here open source library to import contact from the gmail,yao and etc..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/

thank you

Answer (score 1):

you will need to get the API for each service, some might be easier than others. try an ask specific questions about the problems you find using each one

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenID to do the same. Refer the site: [http://openid.net](http://openid.net/)

Specifically this: http://openid.net/add-openid/

Answer (score 0):

try using with Google.GData.Contacts.dll ,Google.GData.Apps.dll

```
username=your emailid;
 password=email password;
app_name="MyNetwork Web Application!";
DataSet ds = GmailContacts.GetGmailContacts(App_Name, username, password);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```